# Angular2 WebPack Bundling for debugging takes forever

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I used the Angular2 CLI to create my project scaffolding.  It uses Webpack.  When I'm doing development, every time I make a change and save it, Webpack has to recreate the bundles before I can reload my page and see the change.  In reality, it's only 10-12 seconds, but for debugging, this is an eon.  Sometimes it takes 4x the time to bundle and reload the page than it did to make the change.  It's maddening.
Am I doing something wrong?  I haven't changed any of the Angular CLI or webpack settings as I wouldn't even know where to begin.  My project isn't (yet) particularly large - 5-6 pretty simple components so far.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Thanks Fabien and John for the replies.  Unfortunately it looks like I'm SOL because according to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656#issuecomment-239366723), Angular CLI does not provide access to the webpack config.  

Bummer...  :-(

Answer (score 0):

This may help a bit your build, add this at your webpack config ;

```
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
```

also check this out : https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Two options for speeding up webpack during development.

1. You can pre-build libraries using Webpack DLL's.  This basically takes a javscript file (i.e. vendor.ts) with a list of the modules you want to prebuild, and produces a JS file that will automatically be used the next time you build webpack instead of building each of those modules again and again.
2. You can use HMR (hot module reloading).  This means that you can run webpack once, and it will wait for you to make any future changes to any of the source files (javascript/html/CSS/LESS/etc).  When you hit Save, webpack-dev-server will detect that you have changed a file, and will JUST BUILD THAT ONE FILE and will automatically transfer it to the browser using sockets, and the browser will only update that one module and any dependent modules.  You can even keep the same app state so you don't have to refresh your browser, and the browser state will continue where you left off before your save.